# How to solve the following system of linear differential equation with variable coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have tried with some methods but cannot proceed the following system of differential equations:

$$\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}v_1(t)=-v_1(t) \cos(t)\sin(t)+v_2(t) \sin^2(t)\\ \displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} v_2(t)=-v_1(t) \cos^2(t)+v_2(t) \cos(t)\sin(t)$$

Can someone help me what method to use to solve this system of equations. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a mistahe ? You have $v_1,v_2$ in LHS